# 'wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)' error when using link_to to pass variable from view to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, argument-passing, link-to

I'm trying to use link_to to pass a variable from a view to a controller. Here's what my code in the view looks like:

```
<%= link_to 'Send Chant', :controller => 'send_chants', :action => 'index', :content => @chant.content %></b>
```

Here's what the index action in my 'send_chants' controller looks like:

```
class SendChantsController < ApplicationController
  def index(content)

    puts content

  end
end
```

Upon clicking the 'Send Chant' link, I get a ArgumentError 'wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)'

I'm sure I'm missing something simple. Any thoughts?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Controller actions do not take parameters. All params are passed in via the params hash..  Try something like...

```
class SendChantsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    puts params[:content]
  end
end
```

Comment: super helpful - thank you! SO is requiring me to wait 6 more mins before i can accept the answer. i'll be sure to do so.